# firebase update function, overwrite data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I firebase like bellow. I want to add new item to likes array, by update it. My problem is, when i try to execute my update function, it overwrite other data in likes array.
here is code:

```
db.collection("posts").doc(postId).update({likes :[{username: username, isLiked: true}]})
```

[image: Firebase look:]

Comment: Please edit the question to be more clear about what the document looks like both before and after the update, and explain what it is that you didn't expect to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `update` can update specific fields, it will always overwrite the entire field. So your code replaces the entire `likes` array with the value you pass in the `update` call.

To update an array in a Firestore document, you can two options:

1. Read the document, get the existing values from the document, update the values, write back the entire array.
2. Merge a new item into the array if it doesn't exist yet.

Given your use-case, it seems that you need to merge, which is also the easiest option:

```
db.collection("posts").doc(postId)
  .update({likes : firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({username: username, isLiked: true})})
```

The above code adds the combination of `username` and `isLiked` to the array only if that combination doesn't exist yet.

For a longer explanation, see the documentation on [updating elements in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array), and the section on [updating fields in nested objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects) that can also be useful in similar use-cases.